# Pandas: Import multiple CSV files and append together so that the elements line up according to the time index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

I have several hundred CSV files that come from different sensor data points. They measure energy flow hourly. They were installed at staggered times throughout the year, so each data file begins on a different start date and time.

The final result will be an Excel file indexed by date and time (MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS) for the entire year. Each new horizontal columns will contain a sensor's data set. I need each sensor's data to line up with the final Excel file time index. I want to fill in missing elements with zero where data does not exist before a sensor was installed.

Example Sensor 1 CSV data file:

```
METER_ID, INTERVAL_DATE, INTERVAL_TIME, ENERGY
CC12345, 2/13/2019, 9:00:00, 1.332
CC12345, 2/13/2019, 10:00:00, 0.728
CC12345, 2/13/2019, 11:00:00, 1.583
CC12345, 2/13/2019, 12:00:00, 1.136
CC12345, 2/13/2019, 13:00:00, 0.888
CC12345, 2/13/2019, 14:00:00, 1.240
...
```

Example Sensor 2 CSV data file:

```
METER_ID, INTERVAL_DATE, INTERVAL_TIME, ENERGY
AA98765, 2/13/2019, 12:00:00, 0.498
AA98765, 2/13/2019, 13:00:00, 0.517
AA98765, 2/13/2019, 14:00:00, 1.223
...
```

...Hundreds of Sensor files later...

The final result will be in an Excel file and would look like:

```
DATETIME,          CC12345, AA98765, ... 
1/1/2019 00:00:00, 0.000,   0.000
1/1/2019 01:00:00, 0.000,   0.000
1/1/2019 02:00:00, 0.000,   0.000
...
2/13/2019 09:00:00, 1.332,   0.000
2/13/2019 10:00:00, 0.728,   0.000
2/13/2019 11:00:00, 1.583,   0.000
2/13/2019 12:00:00, 1.136,   0.498
2/13/2019 13:00:00, 0.888,   0.517
2/13/2019 14:00:00, 1.240,   1.223
...
12/31/2019 23:00:00, ...
```

I'm brand new to Python and Pandas and here is what I have frankensteined together from other Stack Exchange answers so far. I am stuck and do not know if I am overcomplicating this or if there is a simpler method or procedure already out there to do this.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter

path = 'C:\\Users\\CMBel\\Python Scripts'
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.csv'))    
importColumnFields=['METER_ID','INTERVAL_DATE','INTERVAL_TIME','ENERGY']
newDateIDX=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019 00:00:00',end='12/31/2019 23:00:00',freq='H')


np_array_list = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=importColumnFields, parse_dates=[[2,3]]) #import files and parse INTERVAL_DATE and INTERVAL_TIME together
    df = df.reindex(newDateIDX, fill_value=0)  #Re-index to the final Excel's year long index

    # ?? Not sure where to go from here or if I am on the right track

    np_array_list.append(df.as_matrix(),axis=1)  #Append new ENERGY columns horizontally

np_array_list.to_excel('TestExport.xlsx',index_label='DATETIME')
```

Any help, ideas, pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a column to each dataframe. For a quick example, I called your first csv, df1, and the second csv df2. Then append the datasets together. Lastly you can make a pivot table. This should get you what you are looking for.

```
#Make datetime
df1['DateTime']=df1['INTERVAL_DATE']+" "+df1['INTERVAL_TIME']
df2['DateTime']=df2['INTERVAL_DATE']+" "+df2['INTERVAL_TIME']
#Append both datasets together
df3=df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
df3
#Pivot
pd.pivot_table(df3,values='ENERGY',index='DateTime',columns=['METER_ID']).reset_index()
```